# How to form a connect message in http2? (library: nghttp2, language: C)

Tags: c, http2, nghttp2

I try to send a connection message to a server but I get a response from the server with the status 400 (Bad request).
I understand from RFC that the ":scheme" and ":path" pseudo-header fields MUST be omitted, so I put in the header just :method and :authority

```
  nghttp2_nv hdrs[] = {
      MAKE_NV2(":method", "CONNECT"),
      MAKE_NV(":authority", authority, authoritylen),
      };

 nghttp2_submit_request(session, NULL, hdrs, ARRLEN(hdrs), NULL, NULL);
```

What I did wrong?